# Prevent double clicking stream

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming

ive created a flash stream player with 2 buttons a play and a stop
everything works fine except if the play button is pressed a second time without hitting stop it will double the stream. ive tried adding code to stop double click but after hitting stop the stream will not play again unless I refresh player. I am new to coding so please make your answers accordingly  thanks

```
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

// Objects and Vars
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10);
var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();
var SoundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://209.105.250.69:8548/;");
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
myMusic.load(SoundFile);

// Listeners;
btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMusic);
btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMusic);
sldVolume.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,changevolume);
//sldPan.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,changepan);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime); 
myMusic.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,getSongLength);

function convetTime(millis:Number):String
{
var Seconds:Number = ((millis % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60)) /1000;
var Minutes:Number = (millis % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60);
return (Math.floor(Minutes) + ":" + Math.floor(Seconds));
}


function getSongLength(evt:Event):void
{
lblSongTotalTime.text = (myMusic.length/1000).toString();
}

//function changepan(evt:SliderEvent):void
//{
//sTransform.pan = sldPan.value;
//channel.soundTransform = sTransform;
//}

function updateTime(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
//  lblSongTime.text = convertTime(channel.position);
barGreen.height = (channel.rightPeak *40);
barRed.height = (channel.leftPeak *40);

}

function changevolume(evt:SliderEvent):void
{
sTransform.volume = sldVolume.value;
channel.soundTransform = sTransform;
}
function stopMusic(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
channel.stop();
}

function playMusic(evt:MouseEvent):void
{

channel = myMusic.play();
myTimer.start();
}
```

I have commented out some features I may use later 
Thanks for any help. also I don't know if its possible to have this autoplay 
 when loaded

```
[My Code][1]
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please fix your code block, follow tips of posting questions

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1: Boolean

Just have a Boolean value that holds the value of whether or not `_playing == true`. This value should get set to true when you press play and prevent play from being executed again if already true. Then pressing the stop button should set this value to false, allowing the play button to be pressed again.

```
// Objects and Vars
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10);
var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();
var SoundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://209.105.250.69:8548/;");
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
var _playing:Boolean = false; // value for toggling when the play and stop buttons get pressed
myMusic.load(SoundFile);


//////// THIS IS THE AUTO PLAY
//
playMusic(); // will call the function that normally gets called with a mouse event

function stopMusic(evt:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    if (_playing == true){
        _playing = false;
        channel.stop();
    }
}

function playMusic(evt:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    if (_playing == false) {
        playing = true;
        channel = myMusic.play();
        myTimer.start();
    }
}
```

You could now also stop the music from within other functions. Let's say you wanted to have a menu that the user could click on that you want the music to stop when he clicks it, if you want the music to stop when the mouse leaves the stage or in any other circumstance you can just call `stopMusic();` which first checks if `_playing == true` and then sets it to `false` and stops the music, but if `_playing == false` it won't try to stop the music or change the value of `_playing`

### Method 2: Add/Remove Event Listeners

A completely different method would be to add and remove the eventListeners as needed. For example, when the play button is pressed remove the eventListener for that button and add the event listener for the stop button. When the stop button is pressed remove the event listener for the stop button and add the event listener for the play button. It could look something like

```
function playMusic(me:MouseEvent):void{
    me.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMusic);
    btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMusic);
    // rest of play music code
}

function stopMusic(me:MouseEvent):void{
    me.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMusic);
    playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMusic);
    // rest of stop music code
}
```

Because this method references the event that triggered it, you can't call these methods without a click event like you could with my first suggestion. If you prefer this nifty adding and removing of event handlers I'll show you how you can decouple the triggering event with this approach the same way we did with my first approach above. Just let me know. I don't want to add too much detail here that you aren't interested in.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply

Comment: ive add a copy of my code  for your review .im only a beginner and not sure where to add said code I understand the var part  but not the private function can that b e anywhere in the code ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to work with your code better. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thank you Neal, it works perfectly now. is it possible to auto play? if not im very happy as is . again thank you for your time

Comment: Yeah, my answer currently shows how to auto play. Do you see at the top where I wrote `playMusic();`? I edited it to draw your attention to it :)

Comment: Which method did you want to go with? My first method or my second method?

Comment: yes thanks again everything works perfectly I went with 1st method as it was easier for me to understand

Comment: Please consider marking this answer as correct (the check mark by the answer... ).  And you got the auto play to work as well?